# Entity Framework 6 Update-Database fails for migration created with -IgnoreChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a DbContext specific to may Domain that has one model class entirely managed by EF, and another that gets mapped to a database view.  To ensure EF doesn't try to create this view that already exists, I added just the view to my DbContext and ran the following command:

```
Add-Migration InitialUnmanaged -IngoreChanges
```

This creates a Migration with an empty Up and Down, which is exactly what I want.  I'm able to update my dev database using this Migration, but whenever I try to add a second Migration that includes my EF-managed model class, I get an error.

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201510151553565_InitialUnmanaged]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

The thing is, I've already applied that explicit Migration, and I can see it in my MigrationHistory table.

> MigrationId
>
> 201510151553565_InitialUnmanaged

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to work around it?

Comment: Try deleting the migration from the table and running the first migration again

Comment: Did you run update-database? That will change the model on the db side.

Comment: There's something very strange going on.  When I reset everything and make my initial Migration include everything, I can update the database just fine, but then it fails when I try to roll that back.

Update-Database -target:0 gives an error saying Target database is already at version 0.

Comment: @SteveGreene, yes.  I'm able to update my dev database using this Migration, but whenever I try to add a second Migration, I get the error.

Comment: Try updating with an explicit connection string [-ConnectionStringName <String>]

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue in your migrations table. Truncate the table, create an initial migration without ignoring anything. Just edit the migration and remove everything out of the up and down methods and then run Update-database. Then you should have no issues creating the next migration.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

When I applied the Migration, it put the Migration History table in the same default schema as the model.  However, when I tried to roll it back, it was looking for the Migration History in the connected user's schema.  Since it wasn't there, it thought the database was at version 0.

I created an OracleDbConfiguration class to specify a custom HistoryContext that specifies the default schema for the Migration History table and I'm able to rollback as expected after applying a Migration.

I verified that I was able to recreate my initial steps and have them work as expected now that I'm explicitly specifying the schema for the Migration History table.

Comment: Many thanks.  Between your answer here and the notes you left at (this question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955486/custom-historycontext-causes-get-migrations-to-fail], I was able to solve the same issue you outlined above using EF for ODP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Either delete the migration or just run Update-Database to put entity back in sync. If it is an empty migration your database will not change.