# Custom HistoryContext causes Get-Migrations to fail

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using Oracle's Entity Framework 12.1.22 (6.121.2.0) and Entity Framework 6.0.0.

I have a custom HistoryContext that ensures the __MigrationHistory table is in the same schema as the rest of the model, because we have multiple applications using the same database.

When I start from scratch and run Update-Database from the Package Manager Console, everything appears to work fine, and the __MigrationHistory table is exactly where I expect it to be.  However, it quickly becomes obvious there's a problem:

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is already at version 0.

PM> Add-Migration 2
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201601221958588_1]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

PM> Get-Migrations
Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
No migrations have been applied to the target database.
```

The problem is that Get-Migrations is not looking in the correct schema for the __MigrationHistory table - it's looking in the user schema for the user named in the connection string.  I verified this by creating a copy of the __MigrationHistory table there, at which point all of the above commands began to work as expected.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=Blue")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("BLUE");
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, MaxLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetHistoryContext("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new MyHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
    }
}

public class MyHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MyHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
        this.defaultSchema = defaultSchema;
    }

    private string defaultSchema;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(this.defaultSchema);
    }
}
```

I used the instructions here: [Customizing the Migrations History Table (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx)